# How to used GroupBy and select column in async

Tags: c#, database, asynchronous, ef-core-2.2

[ERD](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4PbjN.png)

Sorry I'm just learning to use C#, How do I create a grouping function using async ? I want to add up the contract values, I tried with code like this

```
public async Task <IEnumerable<BudgetingData>> GetTotalBudgeting()
        {
            var result = await _context.Budgetings
                .Include(e => e.ProposalBudgeting)
                .Include(e => e.ProposalBudgeting.Division)
                .GroupBy(e => e.ContractValue)
                .AsNoTracking()
                .ToListAsync();
            return result;
        }
```

Budgeting Data

```
public class BudgetingData
{
    [Key]
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public int? ProposalBudgetingId { get; set; }
    public string SubBudgetingProject { get; set; }
    public string ValueProjectEstimation { get; set; }
    public string CurrentYearAllocation { get; set; }
    public string Procurement { get; set; }
    public string StatusProject { get; set; }
    public string ContractValue { get; set; }
    public string LstYear_Realization { get; set; }
    public string LstYear_RemainingPayment { get; set; }
    public string ThsYear_TotalPayment { get; set; }
    public string ThsYear_RemainingPayment { get; set; }
    public DateTime LastUpdate_dt { get; set; }
    public int? StatusId { get; set; }
    public string IsDelete { get; set; }

    public virtual Status Status { get; set; }
    public virtual ProposalBudgeting ProposalBudgeting { get; set; }
}
```

I want to total the contract value of the divisions, for example division 1 has a total contract value of 1000

However, when the error returns result, the error is "Cannot implicitly convert type 'type' 1 'type 2'. An explicit conversion exists (are you missing a cast?)"

Comment: If you want to sum contract values, you shouldn't group by them. Also, keep in mind that we don't see your classes etc. What is `BudgetingData`, `_context.Budgetings`, and which output do you expect?

Comment: What is the type of `_context.Budgetings` and what is the purpose of `GroupBy` here?

Comment: I want to total the contract value of the divisions, for example division 1 has a total contract value of 1000

Comment: So at least you'd have to group by `Division` don't you think? But it's still very vague. How should the result consist of `BudgetingData` entities?

Comment: The `BudgetingData` entity relates to the `PropBudgeting` table and the `PropBugeting` table relates to the `division` table. The data currently available, 1 division has several budgeting data. Therefore I want to add up the total budgeting for each division

Comment: The question remains - how do you expect to return a `IEnumerable<BudgetingData>` from this calculation of the total budgetting for each division? Surely you want to return a collection of division name and total budget?

Comment: Yeah, I want to get the division name and total budget, then how should I make a query to get the total budget for each division ? This is my first time, I've tried searching, but I don't understand

Comment: You still didn't show what `_context.Budgetings` is. Which class does it return? It's totally unclear how you would return `BudgetingData` objects from it. Or what else you want to return if it's not `BudgetingData`.